# Elastic APM Tomcat zip file or JAR manifest missing

Tags: java, elasticsearch, tomcat, apm

I am trying to instrument our java webapp based on tomcat using Elastic APM. Tomcat starts fine without the javaagent but refuses to start with it. I do not see any logs in /var/log/tomcat. The following is the log:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l tomcat.service
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-04-17 01:45:36 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 25660 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/tomcat/server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 25660 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

arguments used: start
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option PermSize; support was removed in 8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /opt/elastic/elastic-apm-agent-1.15.0.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
tomcat.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
tomcat.service failed.
```

Has anyone faced this before? Any ideas what I could do to fix it?

Comment: /opt/elastic/elastic-apm-agent-1.15.0.jar is present and is accessible to the tomcat user

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to give permissions to folder /opt/elastic ?

```
chmod -R uog+x
```